# F-Sharp (F#) untyped infinity

Tags: f#, functional-programming, infinite-loop, infinity, lazylist

I wonder why F-Sharp doesn't support infinity.

This would work in Ruby (but not in f#):

```
let numbers n = [1 .. 1/0] |> Seq.take(n)
```

-> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.

I can write the same functionality in much complex way:

```
let numbers n = 1 |> Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some (i, i + 1)) |> Seq.take(n)
```

-> works

However I think that first one would be much more clear. 
I can't find any easy way to use dynamically typed infinity in F#.
There is infinity keyword but it is float:

```
let a = Math.bigint +infinity;;
```

System.OverflowException: BigInteger cannot represent infinity.
   at System.Numerics.BigInteger..ctor(Double value)
   at .$FSI_0045.main@()
stopped due to error

---

*Edit: also this seems to work in iteration:*

```
let numbers n = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i+1) |> Seq.take(n)
```

Comment: Is it doing integer or floating-point arithmetic? The two have vastly different concepts of infinity.

Comment: That does not work in Ruby. Infinity is a floating-point value in Ruby as well, so you'd need to do floating-point division — 1..1.0/0.

Comment: In this specific case 'let numbers n = seq { 1 .. n }' might be the simplest...

Comment: Johan, the Seq.take(n) is not there in my actual code, it's just here for demo purposes. :-)

Comment: Yes, I guessed that was the case... :) I find the infinity question quite interesting in programming context - and believe that you often actually have a natural limit... - but that's another question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, F# lists are not lazy, (I'm not sure Ruby lists are lazy), so even with a general notion of infinity your first example can never work.

Second, there is no infinity value in Int32. Only MaxValue. There is a positive and negative infinity in Double though.

Putting it together, this works:

```
let numbers n = seq { 1. .. 1./0. } |> Seq.take(n)
```

I feel however Seq.initInfinite is your best option. The code above looks strange to me. (Or at least use Double.PositiveInfinity instead of 1./0.)

At first sight, a nice option to have in the language would be an infinite range operator like in haskell: seq { 1.. } The problem is that it would only work for seq, so I guess the extra work to support postfix operators is not worth it for this feature alone.

Bottom line: in my opinion, use Seq.initInfinite.

Comment: Since Seq.initInfinite is based in Int32 it must, for any practical purpose, be equivalent to 'seq { 1 .. System.Int32.MaxValue }'. Using that construct instead nobody is fooled to believe that any inifinity is actually involved. I would recommend that instead. - Or the unfold approach - when dealing with bigints...

Comment: @Johan: I feel that Seq.initInfinite works better with type inference - the type of the resulting seq should be inferred automatically, whereas with { 1..Int32.MaxValue} you need a call to some constant. So it may be a closer solution to the original question. But indeed, the infinite in initInfinite is a misnomer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following is the best solution to infinite ranges in F#; by marking the function `inline` we do better than "dynamically typed infinity" we get structurally typed infinite ranges (works with int32, int64, bigint, ... any type that which has a static member `+` which takes two arguments of its own type and returns a value of it's own type):

```
let inline infiniteRange start skip = 
    seq {
        let n = ref start
        while true do
            yield n.contents
            n.contents <- n.contents + skip
    }

//val inline infiniteRange :
//   ^a ->  ^b -> seq< ^a>
//    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^a)
```